# Save word2vec model on google drive through colab

Tags: python, word2vec, google-colaboratory

I have created a word2vec using Google Colab. However, when I try to save it using the code that I generally use to save on my computer, the file doesn't appear:

```
model.init_sims(replace=True)
model_name = "Twitter"
model.save()
```